# Sans serif upright lower-case Greek letters for beamer class

Tags: beamer, math-mode, greek, sans-serif

I use the beamer class with the `cmbright` package which provides sans serif Greek and Latin letters for the math mode and also sans serif-ish versions of math symbols such as `\partial`. Unfortunately, it does not seem to provide upright versions of the lower-case Greek letters. I know the `upgreek` package, but the letters it provides have a serif-ish look about them which does not combine nicely with `cmbright`.

Here is what I mean:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[Euler]{upgreek}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\varepsilon\zeta\eta
\theta\vartheta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu\xi\pi\varpi
\rho\sigma\tau\upsilon\phi\varphi\chi\psi\omega$\\
$\upalpha\upbeta\upgamma\updelta\upepsilon\upvarepsilon\upzeta\upeta
\uptheta\upvartheta\upiota\upkappa\uplambda\upmu\upnu\upxi\uppi\upvarpi
\uprho\upsigma\uptau\upupsilon\upphi\upvarphi\upchi\uppsi\upomega$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result (pdflatex):]

Maybe someone knows a solution? Ideally, there should also be a way to get a bold version of the letters. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe using the `mathastex` package: it allows to use any text font  for maths, and to specify if Greek letters are upshape or italic. Other possibility:  use the `MyriadPro`  package, based on the eponymous font which comes with Acrobat Reader.

Comment: @Bernard Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comment